# Polygons getting named multiple times using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, symbology, spatial-join

I was looking at a dataset of votes in California and wanted to get a normalized map of voting trend. The dataset I had was of precinct votes in county and polygons of the counties. I completed the normalization of the data by using "Spatial Join" tool and merging the data into output. I wanted to name the counties in the output based on their name. However when I was trying to label the features the output map was taking too much time to render and after it got rendered there were multiple names for the same polygon.

After doing it multiple times it got fixed but I still do not know what the core issue was.

Did I use the "Merge rule" within "Spatial Join" tool in a wrong way?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have duplicate geometries, or multipart polygons

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to state what you changed to fix it, which will make it easier to explain *why* what you did worked.

Comment: If you are joining precinct to county, then you'll end up with a dataset of as many county polygons as there are are precincts in the county. Hence the duplicated labels. You could use the delete identical tool to remove duplicate geometries.

Comment: The most important info for a join is how many records you have after the join. In other words, open the attribute table before deciding what the next step is (a dissolve, symboloizing, etc.)